# What setting decides how vs code searches for python import suggestions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-completion

Using python in VS Code I was always able to press ctrl+space to get code suggestions, both for finishing arguments and for imports. For some reason now only code completion is shown, but no import suggestions.

Consider the following:

```py
def system_thingy():
    pass

sys #cursor here
```

Before, pressing ctrl+space would suggest both the system_thingy function, as well as an import of the sys module. Now only the function is shown.

What setting in VS code manages these suggestions? How do I turn on the import suggestions again?

Comment: `"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,` Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic import feature is disabled by default in the November 2022 version, and you need to enable it manually.

> #### [Auto imports turned off by default with Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-november-2022-release/#auto-imports-turned-off-by-default-with-pylance)
>
> Since auto imports were first implemented in Pylance, we’ve been getting a lot of feedback about how confusing and, sometimes, annoying it could be to have an import automatically added to a file when, for example, suggestions are accepted by accident. Starting this release, packages will no longer be imported automatically by default when using Pylance.

Add the following settings in your *setttings.json*:

```json
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
```

Or search for `python.analysis.autoImportCompletions` in the **Settings** panel and check it

[image]